# Query concatenates everything into one row rather than into separate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, concatenation

I have the following tables

```
Customer (driver_id is UNQIUE)
+--------+------+-----------+
| cus_id | name | driver_id |
+--------+------+-----------+
|      1 | bob  |      2342 |
|      2 | sam  |      2463 |
+--------+------+-----------+

Items (manufacture_product_id is UNIQUE) 
+---------+-------+-------------------------+
| item_id | name  | manufacturer_product_id |
+---------+-------+-------------------------+
|       1 | shirt |                    2131 |
|       2 | jeans |                     383 |
|       3 | pants |                       2 |
|       4 | watch |                   34634 |
|       5 | belt  |                       5 |
+---------+-------+-------------------------+

Outfits
+-----------+--------+---------------------+
| outfit_id | cus_id |    creation_date    |
+-----------+--------+---------------------+
|         1 |      2 | 2020-01-28 12:31:00 |
|         2 |      2 | 2020-01-29 15:23:12 |
+-----------+--------+---------------------+

items_in_outfit
+----------------+-----------+---------+
| outfit_item_id | outfit_id | item_id |
+----------------+-----------+---------+
|              1 |         1 |       2 |
|              2 |         1 |       3 |
|              3 |         1 |       5 |
|              4 |         2 |       1 |
|              5 |         2 |       2 |
|              5 |         2 |       3 |
|              6 |         2 |       5 |
+----------------+-----------+---------+
```

Just to summarize the above. The `customer` `sam` has 2 outfits with the `outfit_id's` `1` and `2`. Outfit `1` contains the `items_id's`, `2,3,4`. Outfit `2` contains the `items_id's`, `1,2,3,5`.

`item_id's` are useless bits of data but I need it to hold primary key integrity. What I really care about is the `manufacturer_product_id`. How do I select all of `cus_id=2's` outfits in a concatenated string of `manufacturer_product_id's`. So my output would be:

```
+-----------+--------------------------+---------------------+
| outfit_id | manufacturer_product_str |    creation_date    |
+-----------+--------------------------+---------------------+
|         1 | 2,383,34634              | 2020-01-28 12:31:00 |
|         2 | 2,5,383,2131             | 2020-01-29 15:23:12 |
+-----------+--------------------------+---------------------+
```

However the output I get is

```
+-----------+--------------------------+---------------------+
| outfit_id | manufacturer_product_ids |    creation_date    |
+-----------+--------------------------+---------------------+
|         1 | 2,2,5,383,383,2131,34634 | 2020-01-28 12:31:00 |
+-----------+--------------------------+---------------------+
```

Which is essentially combining all of `outfit_id = 1` and `outfit_id = 2` together. I want each outfit_id to be separate.

```
SELECT o.outfit_id, o.creation_date,
       GROUP_CONCAT(i.manufacturer_product_id ORDER BY i.manufacturer_product_id) as manufacturer_product_ids
FROM outfits o INNER JOIN
     items_in_outfit io
     ON o.outfit_id = io.outfit_id JOIN
     items i
     ON io.item_id = i.item_id JOIN
     customer c
     ON o.cus_id = c.cus_id 
WHERE c.driver_id = 2463
ORDER BY o.creation_date;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `group by` clause

```
 SELECT o.outfit_id, o.creation_date,
           GROUP_CONCAT(i.manufacturer_product_id ORDER BY i.manufacturer_product_id) as manufacturer_product_ids,
           GROUP_CONCAT(i.manufacturer_product_id ORDER BY i.manufacturer_product_id SEPARATOR ';') as manufacturer_product_ids_sep
    FROM outfits o INNER JOIN
         items_in_outfit io
         ON o.outfit_id = io.outfit_id JOIN
         items i
         ON io.item_id = i.item_id JOIN
         customer c
         ON o.cus_id = c.cus_id 
    WHERE c.driver_id = 2463
    group by o.outfit_id,o.creation_date
    ORDER BY o.creation_date
```

Comment: Thanks, thats the answer. I will mark as answer once the timer lets me

Comment: @glad that it helped u :)

Comment: Can I just ask one additional question, What if I wanted to do the same thing (but I wanted one column which separated with `,` and one that separated with `;` in the results. So its still the same logic, but just different delimiters. How would I do that the most efficient way?

Comment: @James, you can use GROUP_CONCAT(yourcolumn SEPARATOR ';')

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you show me an example

Comment: @James, do you want two columns of group concat ? one with comma and another with semicolon?

Comment: @James, then add one extra column with seperator

Comment: @James, I've added the column